# Pass the contents of a file to an array and print it

Tags: arrays, file, readfile

Hi all I'm stuck at an exercise I have to create a txt file fill it with random integers,then read the file to an array sort it and then print it out at another file Here is my code so far:

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int *A;
int numbers,lines=0;
srand(time(0));

ofstream myfile;

myfile.open("integers.txt");

if (myfile.fail())
   {
      cout << "Error";
      return 1;
   }

cout<<"\nHow many numbers the file contain : ";
cin>>numbers;
cout<<"\n";


if(myfile.is_open()){

for (int i = 0; i < (numbers-1); ++i) {

myfile << rand()%100 <<"\n";
}
}
A=new int[lines];

ifstream myfile1;
myfile1.open("integers.txt");
 if(myfile1.fail())
    {
      cout << "Error" << endl;
      return 1;
    }

while (!myfile1.eof())
    {
        myfile1 >> A[lines];
        lines++;
    }
    for(int k=0;k<lines;k++)
        cout<<A[k]<<endl;

myfile.close();



return 0;

}
```

So the problem is how to read the content of the file to the array. Whenever I print the array after I read the file the output is crap.I have Googled it and find various solutions but none of these seem to work properly.Can someone tell me what my mistake is?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you created a zero-length array here, as `lines` is initialized to zero.

This line:

```
A=new int[lines];
```

should probably be:

```
A=new int[numbers]
```

Comment: Nope still the same problem the numbers in the file are not the in the array,in fact when I print the array it just shows a long number which is completely irrelevant with the other numbers

Comment: sorry guys but it doesn't work this way, don't know why, the problem is still the same as I mentioned above.